# Continue to sync with Dropbox after logging out

Tags: linux, debian, dropbox

I use Dropbox in Debian. I would like to continue syncing the Dropbox folder after logging out.

Is there a way to run the daemon in background at startup? Are there other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
nohup ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
```

nohup makes sure that the process is not killed when you log out.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/131973-dropbox-headless-workstation?page=1#entry-6076539

un user mentioned:

> Just thought I'd mention:
>
> (a) the latest distributions seem to make this fairly straightfoward,
>   just run "dropbox start" from the command line, BUT
>   (b) watch out for
>   logging in and out with X11 forwarded.
>
> I've set up a lot of bash aliases for connecting to various machines,
>   and they all include the "-X" option to forward X11 packets.  Because
>   of this, dropbox kept dying on my on logout, even running it under
>   'screen' and with nohup.  Apparently, having X11 forwarded was causing
>   dropbox to connect the dbus process on my local machine rather than on
>   the remote machine; so, when I broke the connection, dropbox was
>   seeing dbus as having terminated and thus was terminating itself. 
>   Just FYI, as this stumped me for a bit.  The key was that I was having
>   to press Ctrl-C even after logging out / running 'exit' on the remote
>   machine.  Apparently, ssh was keeping the session open, even though I
>   had exited bash, because of the remaining open connection.

And then another user commented:

> The solution is simple even if one (for some reason) wants to keep
>   ssh-ing with the '-X': before launching dropbox you should "break" the
>   forwarding for example doing:
>
> unset DISPLAY
>
> if this is done in a stupid bash script the forwarding is "broken"
>   just inside the script but once this is executed the 'terminal' is
>   still forwarding.

Comment: As the solution is quite simple, and the quotes are rather long, it would make your answer better if you summarised the solution first and only after that had those quotes for those who are interested in the details.